# UTF Coding for CSV import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am attempting to import a csv file into a rails application. I followed the directions given in a RailsCast > http://railscasts.com/episodes/396-importing-csv-and-excel

No matter what I do, however I still get the following error:

ArgumentError in PropertiesController#import

invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 Products.

I'm hoping someone can help me find a solution.

Comment: What code have you written? Fixing that is easier than writing something from scratch for you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the CSV documentation? The [`open`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.2/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html#method-c-open) method, along with `new` support multibyte character conversions on the fly:

> You must provide a mode with an embedded Encoding designator unless your data is in Encoding::default_external(). CSV will check the Encoding of the underlying IO object (set by the mode you pass) to determine how to parse the data. You may provide a second Encoding to have the data transcoded as it is read just as you can with a normal call to IO::open(). For example, "rb:UTF-32BE:UTF-8" would read UTF-32BE data from the file but transcode it to UTF-8 before CSV parses it.